# How to open a collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

A database is created in MongoDB using mongoengine, documents were updated to that database, now I want to open that database in MongoDB, MongoDB is showing the database but not showing any documents from that database(collection).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are looking at the same database and collection (names) that were used for data entry.